# How to view webpage source code using R?

Tags: javascript, r

I need to use R to download the source code for a webpage.

When I click on "View source code" in Firefox, I see all of the source code.
However, when I use RCurl to download the sourcecode, I only see a part of it. The parts that are missing are produced by Javascript, so maybe that's the problem? Can RCurl not see Javascript-produced information?

How can I get the source code into R? Either through RCurl like I've tried or into a txt file, THEN loaded into R would be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/index.html) text browser has some javascript support. See the docs for how to configure/enhance this support:

```
elinks -dump www.google.com
```

will give you the rendered version of the site.

A better option is to use [mozrepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki). It connects to firefox and from the command prompt you can do whatever you can do from the webpage javascript:

```
telnet localhost 4242
repl> var w=window.open("https://google.com")
repl> w.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

should give you the page.

The question is how to make this work with R:

```
mz <- socketConnection("localhost", "4242")
writeLines("var w=window.open(\"https://google.com\")\n",mz)
out <- readLines(mz) #empty the buffer
writeLines("w.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML\n", mz)
out <- readLines(mz)
str(out)
```

should give:

```
 chr [1:73] "repl> repl> \"<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><meta itemprop=\"image\" content=\"/"| __truncated__ ...
```

which you can further filter for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`RCurl` just handles the HTTP part of the transfer; it does not have a Javascript interpreter to execute the code in the page (which may download additional HTML or write it directly). You will need to find a command line program which can both download a URL and execute the accompanying Javascript and then save the result to a file. You can call this program using `system()`, then.

Comment: thanks
any suggestions on a command line program that will do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with any program that does that. I thought maybe you could get firefox to do it, but I didn't see anything obvious in my very quick search.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with exactly the same task for a couple of weeks. I would suggest that the most straightforward way is using `rsDriver` from the RSelenium library. The RSelenium basics vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html gives an overview.

```
 library(RSelenium)

 rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)

 remDr <- rD$client

 remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")

 XML::htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
```