# How do I download the source code for a webpage with tags created by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, r

How do I download through R the source code for a webpage that has tags that were created by JavaScript?

When I use the FireFox ‘Inspect Element’ function, tags are sometimes not shown in the HTML source file. In other words, information I need is in the JavaScript code. Is there a way to read this information into R?

*Related question: [How to view webpage source code using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778076/how-to-view-webpage-source-code-using-r?rq=1)*

Comment: To execute JavaScript and build a DOM, you need a browser (driven by R).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess for my purpose of scraping the page, this doesn't seem like a solution worthwhile - amount of time spent would be too great for the information I need. Is there no way to scrape a page in R with JavaScript elements?

Comment: @chunsangh, can you tell us what webpage you're talking about and what you're trying to get from it?

Comment: For an example: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4356115?tstart=0
<strong class="jive-thread-reply-message-correct-label"></strong> is the element I'm interested in, which I can see using FireFox's built in 'Inspect Element'. However, this tag will not show up in HTML source code.

Comment: I see it using `getURL` from [**RCurl**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RCurl).  You just want to extract "This solved my question"?

Comment: That was just an example of type of the problem I was facing. I assumed RCurl wouldn't work based on another question asked on SO, but I'll definitely I will give RCurl a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getURL` from [**RCurl**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RCurl) to get the HTTP response.

```
library(RCurl)
address <- "https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4356115?tstart=0"
txt <- getURL(address)
```

Now you can spit the string on the opening tag, then split that on the closing tag

```
ss <- strsplit(txt, "<strong class=\"jive-thread-reply-message-correct-label\">")[[1]]
strsplit(ss[2], "</strong>")[[1]][1]
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "This solved my question"
```

---

It turns out that there is more than one of the div tag you wanted, and the above gets the wrong one.  I don't know how to do it purely in R, but I followed [the post you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790136/967840) by [VitoshKa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453735/vitoshka) and I got it to work.

First, in Firefox go to Tools -> Add-ons.  Search for and install mozrepl.  Then, in Firefox click Tools -> MozRepl -> Start.

Now, in **R**:

```
mz <- socketConnection("localhost", "4242")
writeLines("var w=window.open(\"https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4356115?tstart=0\")\n",mz)
out <- readLines(mz) #empty the buffer
writeLines("w.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML\n", mz)
out <- readLines(mz)

(loc <- grep("jive-thread-reply-message-correct-label", out))
#[1] 1150 2845
```

Now, `out` is a vector`loc` holds the positions of the strings that contain your tag.  It appears twice.  The first one is the one you're interested in.

```
out[loc[1]]
```

You can extract the information from this the same way I showed above with `strsplit`, or with a regular expression and `gsub`

---

You can close the window that opens with `writeLines("w.window.close()", mz)`

Comment: Thanks GSee. Exactly what I was looking to do. Cheers!

Comment: GSee, it turns out "This solved my question" you retrieved was part of 'Legend' on the right-hand side of the page. I was interested in knowing if the thread had "This solved my question" reply or not.

Comment: @chunsangh Oops, your request wasn't specific enough ;-).  Sorry.

Comment: On that note, any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts GSee :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run a full javascript interpreter on the html.

You can use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino). It will be slow.

Otherwise you will need to drive a browser like [selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) does. (You can use the selenium .net libraries)

You would be better off figuring out what the javascript does by inspection, rather than naive scraping.

Also learn XPATH queries if you are serious about scraping.